# $\int^x_0 f (t) $dt =F(x) for every  ∈ [0,2]

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int^x_0 f (t) $dt =F(x) for every  ∈ [0,2]

I need to find all x where : F'(x) = f(x)

1.
$$
f(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
0,  \   ≤ 1  \\ 
1 ,  > 1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

2.
$$
f(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
1,  \   = 1/n  \\ 
0 ,  ≠ 1/n
\end{array}
\right.
$$

3.
$$
f(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
1,  \   ≠ 0  \\ 
1/
[
1/

] ,  = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: I think I should use  The Fundamental theorem of calculus, but I don't real know how..@SK19

Answer (score 2):

I show you 1.:

If $0 \le x \le 1$ we have $F(x)= \int_0^x 0 dx=0$.

If $1 <x \le 2$ we have $F(x)=  \int_0^1 0 dx+ \int_1^x 1 dx=x-1$.

Thus:

$$F(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
0,  \  0 \le  ≤ 1  \\ 
x-1 , 1<x \le 2
\end{array}
\right..$$